# Como usar ng-repeat em uma lista de um objeto?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angularjs-scope

Como usar `ng-repeat` no atributo RegioesFilhas do objeto?

Exemplo: `ng-repeat="item in objeto.RegioesFilhas`

**Objeto:**

```
   var objeto = {
       "DescricaoRegiaoVaga": "",
       "IdCidadeCorreios": "1",
       "RegioesFilhas": [{
           "Cidade": "Brasília",
           "UF": "DF",
           "ID": "1"
       }, {
           "Cidade": "Asa Sul",
           "UF": "DF",
           "ID": "2"
       }],
       "Cidade": {
           "UF": "DF",
           "Cidade": "Brasília"
       }
   }
```

Comment: Veja se esse post te ajuda: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21703722/angularjs-ng-repeat-setting-attributes

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Você pode fazer dessa maneira:

Ao invés de utilizar `var objeto` mude para `$scope.objeto` pois dessa forma você fará o binding com o `Html` no `ng-repeat`.

Depois é só fazer o `binding` com os dados no componente que você deseja, nesse caso utilizei uma lista.

Leitura recomendada:

https://docs.angularjs.org/tutorial/step_04

https://docs.angularjs.org/guide/scope

---

Exemplo:

```js
var myApp = angular.module('myApp', []);

function MyCtrl($scope) {

$scope.objetos = {
       "DescricaoRegiaoVaga": "",
       "IdCidadeCorreios": "1",
       "RegioesFilhas": [{
           "Cidade": "Brasília",
           "UF": "DF",
           "ID": "1"
       }, {
           "Cidade": "Asa Sul",
           "UF": "DF",
           "ID": "2"
       }],
       "Cidade": {
           "UF": "DF",
           "Cidade": "Brasília"
       }
   }

}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.23/angular.min.js"></script>
<div ng-app="myApp" ng-controller="MyCtrl">
 <ul ng-repeat="objeto in objetos.RegioesFilhas">
  <li>{{objeto.Cidade}}</li>
  <li>{{objeto.UF}}</li>
  <li>{{objeto.ID}}</li>
</ul> 
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

Olá, tenta definir como `$scope.objeto` ou invés de `var = objeto`.
Aqui rodou bonitinho

Answer (score 1):

Este exemplo demonstra exatamente o seu propósito: https://jsfiddle.net/9am2enqy/11/

Basta adicionar a variável ao escopo.